# CodeIgniter page caching with a exception

Tags: codeigniter, caching

I like to use [CodeIgniters page caching](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/caching.html). But I've got a views counter in the controller, something like:

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE tb_product SET popularity=popularity+1 WHERE product_id=".$this->db->escape($this->uri->segment(2))."");
```

Is it possible to use page caching but make a exception to run this query only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer, but I've striped the counter out and wrote a cronjob which will get statistics from Google Analytics trough GAPI.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You could try to implement a hook. This would have to be the 'cache_override' hook. You could do the DB call from the hook.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html

Your hook method will have to call the original caching itself after doing the DB call.

```
function your_hook( )
{  

    // your DB code here

    // Use some CI globals for this, see /system/core/Codeigniter.php
    if ($OUT->_display_cache($CFG, $URI) == TRUE)
    {
        exit;
    }
}
```

You could write a custom Output.php class and override (decorate) the original _display_cache method. Place your MY_Ouput.php in the /application/core directory and CI will use it automatically.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

Put something like this in it:

```
class MY_Output extends CI_Output
{
    function _display_cache( &$CFG, &$URI )
    {
        // your DB call

        // The original call
        return parent::_display_cache( $CFG, $URI );
    }

}
```

I didn't try this myself, but it should help you on your way. One of these will probably work. Good luck!